# how to create multiple JSON Object dynamically?

Tags: java, android, json, dynamic

I am trying to insert data into multiple JSON objects but I don't know how to create them dynamically in android.

In the hard coded way it is something like:-

```
JSONArray pdoInformation = new JSONArray();

JSONObject pDetail1 = new JSONObject();
JSONObject pDetail2 = new JSONObject();
JSONObject pDetail3 = new JSONObject();

pDetail1.put("productid", 1);
pDetail1.put("qty", 3);
pDetail1.put("listprice", 9500);

pDetail2.put("productid", 2);
pDetail2.put("qty", 4);
pDetail2.put("listprice", 8500);

pDetail3.put("productid", 3);
pDetail3.put("qty", 2);
pDetail3.put("listprice", 1500);

pdoInformation.put(pDetail1);
pdoInformation.put(pDetail2);
pdoInformation.put(pDetail3);
```

**But I want to create these `JSONObject` dynamically as I don't know how many of them are going to be needed while coding and in those dynamically created  `JSONObject` the data will be filled from three `ArrayList` of `productid`, `qty` and `listprice`.**

*So its obvious that the number of those dynamically created `JSONObject` will depend on the `size` of any one `ArrayList`.*

`ArrayList` :-

```
ArrayList<String> productid = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> qty = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> listprice= new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: you want send data without names ?without keys?

Comment: @DIVA with name and key

Comment: post your arraylist to get complete code

Comment: size of all of them are equal , yes?

Comment: @mmlooloo yes all are same

Comment: is it possible to attach a number to the name of `JSONObject` with every iteration??

Comment: yes, obj.put("name",value);

Comment: @mmlooloo no I meant like in first iteration the JSON object's name is `pDetail1` in second `pDetail2`. Something like this??

Comment: why you want name, to reference them later? so use index instead look at my new comment in my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 List<JSONObject> myJSONObjects = new  ArrayList<JSONObject> (productid.size()); 

for(int i=0; i<productid.size(); i++) {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("productid", productid.get(i) );
    obj.put("qty", qty.get(i));
    obj.put("listprice", listprice.get(i));

   myJSONObjects.add(obj);

}
```

at the end all JSONObjects are in myJSONObjects.

Comment: will it store the data like:- `{{productid:1, qty:3, listprice:9500}, {productid:2,qty:2, listprice:8500}}` or {productid:1, qty:3, listprice:9500, productid:2, qty:2, listprice:8500}`???

Comment: this store json object , not json array , for example it stores {productid:1, qty:3, listprice:9500} at  myJSONObjects.get(0); and 
{productid:2,qty:2, listprice:8500} at myJSONObjects.get(1); and so ...

Comment: Okay, I will let you know after testing it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

> I want to create these JSONObject dynamically as I don't know how many
>   of them are going to be needed while coding.

As you are already having `ArrayList`, iterate through it and create a new `JSONObject` in each iteration and put it inside `ArrayList<JSONObject>`.

**For example:**
JSONObject objJSON;

```
for(int i=0; i<numberOfItems; i++) {
    objJSON = new JSONObject();
    objJSON.put("productid", 1);
    objJSON.put("qty", 3);
    objJSON.put("listprice", 9500);

    pdoInformation.put(objJSON);
}
```

> The data will be filled from three ArrayList of productid, qty and
>   listprice

You shouldn't take different ArrayLists because you have to manage each lists as many as you have, instead of that create a single ArrayList of type user defined class. For example, `ArrayList<Product>` where Product type would contain setter/getter methods.

Comment: but how will I `put` the data into it as I don't know its name?

Comment: Sir, its almost same except there is no use of `ArrayList` in your code and at that time you didn't responded to my query whereas others were responding. I accepted that answer not only because it worked exactly as I wanted but also because if someone else will come searching for same question then he don't have to do much modifications in code. No disrespect, I even up-voted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In this design, how will you relate data with each other if it is divided in multiple Arraylists.

It seems you need to redesign your data structure a bit.

Instead of using three ArrayLists you should keep one Arraylist.

That Arraylist will hold object of beans.

For ex.

```
class product{
private double productid;
private double listprice;
private long qty;

// getters and setters
}
```

and keep all objects in one Arraylist and then by looping through it you get all three values together while creating JSON.

Comment: will this add the product details of each product in different JSON objects?

Comment: yes..and it is a good way to keep data together.It will ensure you that correct quantity and price is assigned to its productid.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is just a text String. You could simply write something like:

```
    String jsonString = "[";
    jsonString = jsonString  + "{\""productid\":1",\"qty\":3,\"listprice\":9500}";
    jsonString = jsonString  + "{\""productid\":2",\"qty\":4,\"listprice\":8500}";
    jsonString = jsonString  + "{\""productid\":3",\"qty\":2,\"listprice\":1500}";
...
    jsonString = jsonString  + "]";
```

This could be the raw way of doing it.

I am using (not in android but in jsp, so could not be posible) gson and it also works with arraylist object, so you can create the array of objects and after that just ask him to generate the json text.

Comment: obviously there must be a coma betwen each interaction. Just a quick example.